# Chipmunk collisions not happening when moving sprite using actions

Tags: cocos2d-x, chipmunk

Really a basic question, but I am moving a sprite A with a physics body over another kind of sprites B having another physics body. I expect the collision callback oncontact to be called for these bodies. They have their respective category bitmasks set using `setCategoryBitmask()` and also respectively have each other's categories set using `setContactTestBitmask()`.

The collision works as long as I do not move sprite A. I assume the problem is that I move sprite A using cocos2d actions, and I need to do something else. But using cocos2d actions for scripting things like these look so much simpler to me than anything else I can think of.

- Move sprite A using physics calls. (looks like a lot of work, and it looks like it's hard to achieve exact scripting perfection)
- Do my own collision detection in update() instead. (looks like a bunch of work too, especially if the sprites are rotated etc)

Is there any other shortcut? Or did I miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing "Do my own collision detection in update() instead". It wasn't too problematic.

Something like this in update()...

```
const Rect RECT_A = spriteA->getBoundingBox();
for (auto spriteB : someparent->getChildren()) {
    const Rect RECT_B = spriteB->getBoundingBox();
    if (RECT_A.intersectsRect(RECT_B)) {
         // Hit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contaction detection should be fine while collion doesn't work.

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
    scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setGravity(Vec2::ZERO);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{
   if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto createSprite = [this](const Vec2& pos) {
        auto sprite = Sprite::create();
        auto bodyA = PhysicsBody::createCircle(20);
        sprite->setPhysicsBody(bodyA);
        sprite->setPosition(pos);

        bodyA->setCollisionBitmask(0xff);
        bodyA->setCategoryBitmask(0xff);
        bodyA->setContactTestBitmask(0xff);

        return sprite;
    };

    auto spriteA = createSprite(Vec2(300, 300));
    auto moveBy = MoveBy::create(1.f, Vec2(200, 200));
    spriteA->runAction(moveBy);

    auto spriteB = createSprite(Vec2(350, 350));

    addChild(spriteA);
    addChild(spriteB);

    auto contactListener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
    contactListener->onContactBegin = [=](PhysicsContact& contact) {
        auto a = contact.getShapeA()->getBody()->getNode();
        auto b = contact.getShapeB()->getBody()->getNode();

        assert((a == spriteA && b == spriteB) || (a == spriteB && b == spriteA));

        log("It is working");

        return false;
    };

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(contactListener, this);

    return true;
}
```